# How to fix 'Unresolved reference: jdbc' when configuring Jooq with Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, build.gradle, jooq

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 (Ultimate Edition) raises an `Unresolved reference: jdbc` when I try to configure the jdbc driver for code generation with Jooq using the gradle jooq plugin (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin)

I have followed the configuration steps documented here: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#configuration

Content of my `build.gradle.kts`: (compiles when the jdbc block is commented-out)

```
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "3.0.3" apply true
    id("java-library")
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.7")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2")
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
    compile("org.jooq:jooq")
    jooqRuntime("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc")

}

jooq {
    version = "3.11.11"
    edition = JooqEdition.OSS
    jdbc {
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
        user = "postgres"
        password = "postgres"
    }
}
```

Errors return by Gradle when importing the changes are:

```
core/build.gradle.kts
Unresolved reference: jdbc
Unresolved reference: driver
Unresolved reference: url
Unresolved reference: user
Unresolved reference: password
```

Comment: Can you build by Gradle from terminal?

Comment: @Andrey Building from the terminal returns the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [third-party plugin's readme](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), which you're using, you've placed the jOOQ configuration elements on the wrong level. The example given in the readme reads:

```
jooq {
  version = '3.11.11'
  edition = 'OSS'
  sample(sourceSets.main) { // This is relevant here
    jdbc {
      driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
      url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample'
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There was another problem as well: I use a gradle multi projects build and was calling the plugin in the wrong place.